# Scala accessing attribute value in nested Seq collection

Tags: scala

I have a nested `Seq` collection below and I'm trying to access the value of the `height` attribute inside the `Banner` attribute.

Consider that there may exist multiple `Banners` in the list and multiple `Campaigns` in the `Seq` collection. What is the best way to get the value of `height` of each `Banner` in the Banner's List?

I've tried to do it like below but it only prints the value of the entire banner, e.g., `'Banner(1,https://business.eskimi.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/openGraph.jpeg,300,250)'`. I want it to print the value `250` only.

```scala
case class Campaign(id: Int, country: String, targeting: Targeting, banners: List[Banner], bid: Double)
case class Targeting(targetedSiteIds: Seq[String])
case class Banner(id: Int, src: String, width: Int, height: Int)


val lists = Seq(
  Campaign( // Campaign
    1, // Id
    "LT", // Country
    Targeting( // Targeting
      Seq("0006a522ce0f4bbbbaa6b3c38cafaa0f") // TargetedSiteIds
    ),
    List( // Banners
      Banner( // Banner
        1, // id
        "https://business.eskimi.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/openGraph.jpeg", // URL source
        300, // width
        250 // height
      )
    ),
    5d // price
  )
)

activeCampaigns.foreach(_.banners.foreach(el=>println(el)))
```

Comment: There  may exist multiple banners for each campaign and multiple campaigns in the list. What do you expect as output? What type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not well written, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but maybe you can make something out of this.

If I wanted to print those values I would do something like this

```
activeCampaigns.foreach(_.banners.foreach(el => println(el.height)))
```

Comment: This helps a lot. But it only prints 'Banner(1,https://business.eskimi.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/openGraph.jpeg,300,250)'. I want it to print the value of '250'.

Comment: Easy Fix:    activeCampaigns.foreach(_.banners.foreach(el=>println(el.height)))